# Magento: custom folder and file permission issue

Tags: php, magento, permissions

I put a custom folder inside my magento root folder that i want accessed outside.

Like this:

```
magento_root/
magento_root/custom_php/
magento_root/customer_php/accessme.php
```

I want "accessme.php" to be loaded but what happens is that magento seems to search for it in the site itself and shows a 404 error page. How do i allow that to show?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is the file / folder permissions.

Give `custom_php` folder and `accessme.php` file the rights 775 (meaning: execute and read to all; execute, read and write to owner and group).

Comment: Aah, now I get it. I misunderstood your answer. If you could be a little bit more verbose, the answer is easier to understand. I'll edit, see if you like it.